# What approach could be used for modelling virus infections?

Tags: distributions, modeling, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, disease

I'm a physics graduate who ended up doing infosec so most of the statistics I ever learned is useful for thermodynamics. I'm currently trying to think of a model for working out how many of a population of computers are infected with viruses, though I assume the maths works out the same way for real-world diseases so references in or answers relevant to that field would be welcome too.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

- assume I know the total population of computers, N.
- I know the fraction D of computers that have virus-detection software (i.e. the amount of the population that is being screened)
- I know the fraction I of computers that have detection software *that has reported an infection*
- I don't know, but can find out or estimate, the probability of Type I and II errors in the detection software.
- I don't (yet) care about the time evolution of the population.

So where do I go from here? Would you model infection as a binomial distribution with probability like (I given D), or as a Poisson? Or is the distribution different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computer virus propagation is structurally similar to infectious diseases propagation (vaccinations = anti-virus software, virus via email = getting a virus from someone etc).

Use the following links: [Mathematical modelling of infectious disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_modelling_of_infectious_disease) and [Compartmental models in epidemiology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology) as jumping points for your model.

Comment: "Computer virus propagation is structurally similar to infectious diseases propagation " is there a reference for this statement? Typically a viral infection (in living beings) will confer some degree of immunity (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunological_memory), while it's obviously not the case with computer viruses. Also, immunity in living beings may wane (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29766232/). Aren't these differences likely to impact how the two types of virus respectively propagate? (This is not a rhetorical question)